# Why does my path fail if filename contains single-quote/apostrophe?

Tags: python

The file here exists, 100%:

```
path = "~/Music/Youtube_dl/Some Artist - 'On + Off'.m4a"
assert os.path.exists(path)
```

But the above always fails.

If I change my actual file name to test_file.m4a and do:

```
path = "~/Music/Youtube_dl/test_file.m4a"
assert os.path.exists(path)
```

Everything works fine.

So the issue is 100% in the filename. However, I can't see to solve it. I've tried prepending a `u` before the string and all sorts of other solutions but none seemed to help.

Note: I'm getting filenames from an external source and can't control the fact some of them have single quotes/ quotes in them.

Comment: Have you tried copying the very exact file name from terminal? An apostrophe might be something else than what it seems to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` is a shell construct, python knows nothing about it. Even `os.path.exists('~')` fails.  Assuming it is exported, we can use the environment variable `HOME`:

```
import os
import os.path
path = "~/Music/Youtube_dl/Some Artist - 'On + Off'.m4a"

path = path.replace('~', os.environ['HOME'])
assert os.path.exists(path)
```

Alternative you could use `os.path.expanduser` (which is reasonably portable):

```
import os.path
path = "~/Music/Youtube_dl/Some Artist - 'On + Off'.m4a"

path = os.path.expanduser(path)
assert os.path.exists(path)
```

Comment: Ok this worked so I'll probably select it as the correct answer. The weird thing is that `"~/Music/Youtube_dl/test_file.m4a"` does work with `mutagen`, the library I'm using. But the above didn't. `expanduser` did indeed help. But this is VERY weird.

Comment: @zerohedge:  that puzzled me too, the leading `~` is not interpreted by python as a special character (there are several other SO posts on the subject).  Maybe you managed to create a filename with a leading `~`?  It is a legal filename character, although it would be stupid to use it.

Comment: I've confirmed what you say is true. This is epically confusing for me right now. Then what's the point in using `~` at all in Python scripts?

Comment: @zerohedge:   there is no point in using `~` in python except to please users who are used to it.  So far as I know, other non-shell languages don't support `~` directly as a directory name either (although I can't claim to know *all* languages).